# Query to get active processes in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to see what queries are currently running in an oracle DB. However, when I try using the table `v$session` it gives me an error:

[image]

What's the cause of this and what would be the correct way to get the active processes that are running?

I'm looking to get the necessary information to be able to cancel a query for a given user. Let me give an example:

1) User executes query in the application. We add in a comment so we can 'track' that query:

```
/* Query-ID-1283849 */ select * from mytable
```

2) Now, if the user clicks the "Cancel" button while the query is running (let's say the query is taking a very long time to respond), we allow the user to cancel that query, given that the user will probably NOT be a sys user but a 'normal' user with read-only privileges.

How could this be done?

Comment: It means the user you've logged in with does not have the appropriate privileges to query one or both of the views. Check your user's database privileges.

Comment: @SamM -- thanks, is there a way to query the processes that the current user is the owner of?

Comment: Depends on what details you want to get. Edit your question with a list of what you're looking for.

Comment: @SamM thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the question.

Comment: The `select_catalog_role` privilege gives you read access to the main dictionary views including v$session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the fundamental database level, you can't kill individual queries. You kill individual sessions. I'm inferring from your question that your specific use case is inside an application, not a tool like Sql Developer or Sql Plus.

Session killing can be done by users that have special database privileges to kill sessions. If you are inside an application running multiple queries in one session, killing the session will effectively kill your application and require either a) an application restart or b) gracefully programatically handling the dropped session.

If you are using an n-tier ORM framework that handles database interactions for you, you may be in a position where killing the session won't have any affect on your application other than the currently running statement.

Another way in your app to handle isolating sessions and queries is to run a multi-threaded application. Each query spawns a new thread, and the thread can be killed without necessarily killing the session.

Basically, the short answer is you can kill a query only by killing its session. Your approach of looking at v$session is correct and necessary to find the session id for any givel sql statement, you just need to have your DBA grant your privileges to the v$session and v$sql synonyms.

**Update specific to Sql Developer, based on OP's comment for clarification:**

Sql Developer has an option to allow running parallel queries, taking advantage of threads and multiple connections. That setting is found at Tools > Preferences > Database > Worksheet. Regardless of the setting, when you click the query cancel button, the app is still sending a session kill request. The GUI will usually gracefully start a new session and the end user is none the wiser about it. But sometimes things don't work out and the GUI freezes or you end up with no connection and have to manually reconnect.

To add to the complexity, the behavior depends on the driver/client used by your application. OCI, thick clients, and thin clients have shown different behaviors in the past when it comes to kill requests. In fact, in Sql Developer, you have an option to force it to use OCI or a thick driver so that you can avoid certain behaviors.

I'd highly recommend getting rights to view v$session and play around with this. It's fun to learn more about how Oracle manages sessions.

I just discovered that the latest version, Oracle 18c, allows killing an individual query within a session. I'm on 12c so I have not tried this. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-processes.html#GUID-7D8E5E00-515D-4338-8B86-C2044F6D2957

Relevant parts from the documentation.

> 5.10.5 Cancelling a SQL Statement in a Session You can cancel a SQL statement in a session using the ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL statement.
>
> Instead of terminating a session, you can cancel a high-load SQL
>   statement in a session. When you cancel a DML statement, the statement
>   is rolled back.
>
> The following clauses are required in an ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL
>   statement:
>
> SID – Session ID
>
> SERIAL – Session serial number
>
> The following clauses are optional in an ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL
>   statement:
>
> INST_ID – Instance ID
>
> SQL_ID – SQL ID of the SQL statement
>
> You can view this information for a session by querying the GV$SESSION
>   view.
>
> The following is the syntax for cancelling a SQL statement:
>
> ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL 'SID, SERIAL, @INST_ID, SQL_ID';

Comment: thanks for this thorough response. How then would a GUI client such as `SQLDeveloper` from Oracle be handling the Cancel operation when a user cancels their query? For example: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/kill_me_now2.png

Comment: @DavidL I updated my answer to include specifics about Sql Developer and other GUI clients.

Comment: @DavidL One more edit, but it's specific to Oracle 18c. If you happen to be on that version, you are in luck.